# sylius/metadata install in sylis beta 2

Tags: sylius, symfony-3.1

I installed the sylius v1.0.0-beta2 and symfony 3 but I have a bit problems when I install Sylius metadata.
When I launch the command `composer.phar require sylius/metadata-bundle` it return an error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- don't install sylius/resource v0.19.0|don't install sylius/sylius v1.0.0-beta.2
- don't install sylius/resource v0.19.0|remove sylius/sylius v1.0.0-beta.2
- don't install sylius/resource v0.19.0|don't install sylius/sylius v1.0.0-beta.2
- sylius/metadata v0.19.0 requires sylius/resource ^0.19 -> satisfiable by sylius/resource[v0.19.0].
- sylius/metadata-bundle v0.19.0 requires sylius/metadata ^0.19 -> satisfiable by sylius/metadata[v0.19.0].
- Installation request for sylius/metadata-bundle ^0.19.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/metadata-bundle[v0.19.0].
- Installation request for sylius/sylius (locked at v1.0.0-beta.2, required as ^1.0@beta) -> satisfiable by sylius/sylius[v1.0.0-beta.2].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I install it ?